# Need help with Session Management for Decentralized Nextjs app using wagmi Library

Tags: metamask, wagmi, authentication, nextjs, wagmi-hooks

Please find github gist to the source code. where i have implemented Wallet connection using WagmiProvider.

I dont want to repeat adding WagmiProvider to all the pages in my application, instead i want to add it to one place, then all pages in the nextjs application should access it.

i have detailed information & requirement in below github gist

Comment: Hello and welcome! In general, a question should contain any code necessary for a question, as opposed to relying on links. Please try to see if you can rephrase this as either a more general question about using React and wagmi, or include the relevant code; otherwise, the question might be closed. Cheers!